# Ember.js different resources in one namespace

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

Cheers! I have to different resources in one namespace in my rails back-end side:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users, only: [:show] do
      collection do
        get 'profile'
      end
    end
    resource :music, only: [], controller: 'music' do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to separate namespaces 'api/users' and 'api/music' in my rest_adapter?

```
Bandyard.CustomAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: false,
  url: "http://bandyard.dev",
  namespace: 'api/users'
});
```

What if I wll need to grab json from 'api/music' path?

Answer (score 2):

> What if I wll need to grab json from 'api/music' path?

You should just set your ember adapter's namespace to just 'api'. Ember data's REST adapter will add '/music' or '/users' to it based on the name of the model.

See [the rest adapter guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) for details on default naming conventions.

> I need to grab resource 'profile' from 'host/api/users/profile' and 'search' from 'host/api/music/search'. If I set my adapter's namespace to just 'api' it will grab 'profile' resource from 'host/api/profiles'

To customize the endpoint for a specific model, consider overriding either the **[buildURL method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L343)** on your adapter. See the issue **[How to override the URL for a single model in RestAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/775)**

You may also find this pull-request helpful: **[Expose buildURL suffix parameter in findQuery, filter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/825)**

Comment: I need to grab resource `'profile'` from `'host/api/users/profile'` and `'search'` from `'host/api/music/search'`. If I set my adapter's namespace to just `'api'` it will grab `'profile'` resource from `'host/api/profiles'`

Comment: guys? the problem is still here.

Comment: OK. Updated my answer with some options, but it's hard to make a sepcific recommendation because I'm not sure exactly what your API expects. Like is /api/music/search endpoint for searching music records? If so how should PUT/POST/DELETE work? Do you have both users and profiles, or is profiles the only endpoint that matters?

Comment: >  Do you have both users and profiles, or is profiles the only endpoint that matters?
Profile is only that matters, the issue is that the both end-points (profile and search) are in one namespace 'api', but in different resources - users for profile and music for search.